# Plotting a numpy array in healpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, astronomy, healpy

I am attempting to produce a beam on a healpix map, using [healpy](http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). For starters, I would like to be able to produce a 2D gaussian in a mollweide projection, but I really don't know where to begin.

I can define a 2D gaussian:

```
import numpy as np
def gaussian_2D(x,y,mu_x=0.,mu_y=0.,sig_x=1.,sig_y=1.):
    return np.exp(-0.5*(((x-mu_x) / sig_x)**2 + ((y-mu_y) / sig_y)**2))
```

such that I can build up a 3D X, Y, Z space like:

```
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-4, 4, delta)
y = np.arange(-4, 4, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = gaussian_2D(X,Y)
```

but from here I'm pretty lost, and can't track down much useful documentation concerning how and/or what to project. Any suggestions for a direction of attack would be much appreciated!

Comment: `healpy` uses the HEALPix pixelization, so a *map* is a 1D array, where indices correspond to pixels. If you just need a Mollweide projection you can just use `matplotlib`, see http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/geo_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

here is how I do this:

using a small trick. I insert a point at the desired Gaussian centrer and then I use "smearing" to create a Gaussian with some sigma.

Here is some example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import pylab as pl

NSIDE=512 #the map garannularity

m_sm=np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE)) # creates the map
m_sm=m_sm*0. # sets all values to zero

theta=np.radians(80.) # coordinates for the gaussian
phi=np.radians(20.)

indx=hp.pixelfunc.ang2pix(NSIDE,theta,phi) # getting the index of the point corresponding to the coordinates
m_sm[indx]=1. # setting that point value to 1.

gmap=hp.smoothing(m_sm, sigma=np.radians(20.),verbose=False,lmax=1024) # creating a new map, smmeared version of m_sm

hp.mollview(gmap, title="Gaussian Map") #draw it
pl.show()
```

now if you want to do that by hand, you would use a function for a gaussian

1) you feed it some coordinates

2) you retrieve the index corresponding to that coordinate using:

```
indx=hp.pixelfunc.ang2pix(NSIDE,theta,phi)
```

3) you set the value for that point to the value from your gaussian function. i.e.:

```
my_healpy_map[indx]=my_gauss(theta, phy, mean_theta, mean_phy, sigma_theta, sigma_phy)
```